# How to make a custom function as inbuilt

Tags: function-construction, options, functional-style, symbols

I have a custom function like following:

```
SyntaxInformation[
   TwoNumberSameQ] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, OptionsPattern[]}};
Options[TwoNumberSameQ] = {ShowDifference -> False};
TwoNumberSameQ[x_, OptionsPattern[]] := {x, 
  OptionValue[ShowDifference]}
TwoNumberSameQ[a_, b_, OptionsPattern[]] := 
 If[OptionValue[ShowDifference], 
  If[a === b, True, {False, Abs[a - b]}], If[a === b, True, False]]
```

Usage:

```
TwoNumberSameQ[3,4]
```

> False

```
TwoNumberSameQ[3,4,ShowDifference->True]
```

> {False, 1}

```
 TwoNumberSameQ[3,3]
```

> True

I have some dissatisfaction to this function.But the documentation have a little relative explanation for this area.

## Question one

How to make the option have a black color like as a in-built function,but blue like:
[image]

## Question two

How to make `TwoNumberSameQ`'s definition more concise.I just test one option but result so many repetitive code.I cannot imagine how mess when I set three or more option.

## Addtional quesiton

If I can make the option have some optional values to choice.I'll be happy more. :)
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `` Global` `` symbols are blue unless they have a value but if you use any other context that is on `$ContextPath` the symbol color will be black just because it was created.

   So use `` System` `` by mentioning option name when it is parsed for the first time:

   ```
   Options[TwoNumberSameQ] = {System`ShowDifference -> True}
   ```

   or define your function in `Begin/EndPackage` where the option name is exported. Keep in mind conflicts so choose your names wisely.

   ```
   BeginPackage["Numbers`"];

     TwoNumberSameQ; ShowDifference;

   Begin["`Private`"];

     (* your definitions *)
   End[];

   EndPackage[];
   ```

I believe rest of your questions was already answered in:

2. [How to specify and use nested options for a function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91491/5478)

   [How to deal with the condition that a function own many options?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71503/5478)

   [Writing functions with "Method" options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111666/5478)
3. [Prompt a set of possible options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78935/5478)

Comment: You mean I should creat a specific context for those options?

Comment: Maybe Szabolcs have prompt me the color render scheme in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119292/21532),but I cann't apply it in such case.It's pitty.I don't very familiar these.Do you think the following question have a value to ask still?

Comment: It's seem not anyone can get my English.I mean since those question already have solution so that I should close this post? :)

Comment: @yode I know your pain! :) p.s. I think you can live that unless someone complains.

Comment: Thanks for your consideration sincerely.